# How to use framework in Xcode Source Editor Extension?

Tags: xcode, frameworks, editor, target

I'm building an Xcode Editor Extension in Xcode 8.3.2, all go fine until I add framework. I 've used Cocoapods and Carthage, but it warns with `warning: linking against dylib not safe for use in application extensions`

It can run, but the menu under `Editor` is disabled. I tried [How to suppress `warning: linking against dylib not safe for use in application extensions`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28652102/how-to-suppress-warning-linking-against-dylib-not-safe-for-use-in-application) to set `Require Only App-Extension-Safe API` to No, but the menu is still disabled.

I then tried setting `Require Only App-Extension-Safe API` to `YES` for both app target, extension target and the framework that I'm using, still the same problem.

My workaround is to add the source files directly into my extension target. But I would like to use a 3rd framework in my extension

Comment: Did you ever learn how to fix this? I'm having the same issue.